# How to access events under account

Tags: visualforce

I am using recordsetvar with related list to access all contacts and opportunities under a account, but when I try to access events it throws error as  "Events Is Not a valid child relationship name for entity account."
Here's my code.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accs">
<apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="a">
     <apex:pageBlock title="ACCOUNT NAME :: {!a.name}">
            <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" subject="{!a.id}" />
            <apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!a.id}" />
            <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" subject="{!a.id}"/>    
     <!--  <apex:relatedList list="Events" subject="{!a.id}"/>  ERROR:'Events' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Account-->        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: OpenActivities or  ActivityHistories

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" recordSetVar="accs">
<apex:repeat value="{!accs}" var="a">
     <apex:pageBlock title="ACCOUNT NAME :: {!a.name}">
            <apex:relatedList list="Contacts" subject="{!a.id}" />
            <apex:relatedList list="Cases" subject="{!a.id}" />
            <apex:relatedList list="Opportunities" subject="{!a.id}"/>    
     <!--  <apex:relatedList list="**OpenActivities**" subject="{!a.id}"/>  ERROR:'Events' is not a valid child relationship name for entity Account-->        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:repeat>
```

Comment: its openactivities